# What do you call the round blob of hair in this female haircut?

Tags: word-request

[image]

How do you call the round blob of hair in this female haircut? The two blob of hair before the ponytails, what do you call that? Is there a word for it?

Comment: It is a hairstyle, not a haircut. :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is a [bun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bun_(hairstyle)).

> A bun is a type of hairstyle in which the hair is pulled back from the face, twisted or plaited, and wrapped in a circular coil around itself, typically on top or back of the head or just above the neck.

The specific hairstyle is a [double bun](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Bun_(hairstyle)#Double_bun), or a pigtail bun. It's also known as the "odango with pigtails" hairstyle.

Answer (score 2):

The round part is called a

> **bun**
> <sub>NOUN</sub>
>
> A hairstyle in which the hair is drawn back into a tight coil at the back of the head.

From [Lexico](https://www.lexico.com/definition/bun).

See also various images such as [#2: Dutch Braids into Voluminous Buns](https://therighthairstyles.com/20-cool-hairstyles-for-little-girls-on-any-occasion/2/) and others in the series. There are numerous hairstyles that use a bun, and the question asks for the name of the *blob of hair*.